# Vertical Scroll to appear in GridView

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have tried various ways to get a vertical scroll bar to show for my GridView when there are to many rows.

I have tried adding a DIV around the GridView and it looks horrible as its padding like 20px away from my GridView. I there a way so when the information is coming from the database when the GridView hits its maximum height (200px) the GridView will have a scroll bar?

I also don't want my Headers and Rows to have really big Heights when i do this because when i tried setting a height for my GridView they went bigger if there was on 1 piece of data.

CODE:

```
#gv_AcceptedRequests, #gv_PendingRequests, #gv_DeclinedRequests {
position:absolute;
margin-top: 120px;
margin-left: 60px;
width: 480px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
border-color: orange;
overflow: auto;

}
```

Attempt1:

[image]

For some reason the DIV isnt startingat the top of the datagrid?

Comment: There are many suggestions if you just google it. [Here is one](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/11/scrollable-gridview-with-fixed-headers.html)

Comment: @RickS Have just tried and again the scoll bar is appearing with massive padding to the GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide code (html & css) of what you allready made up.

You can place a surrounding DIV around the GridView. The code below places a DIV around your gridview. With a CSS (preferred external CSS file) of overflow-y (shows a vertical scrollbar) and zero padding. If there's still padding left, then there's an issue with the CSS on the page.

```
<div id='scrolldiv' style='position:absolute;border:1px solid black;height:100px;width:650px;overflow-y:scroll;margin-top:120px;margin-left:60px;'>
    <div id='gv_AcceptedRequests' style='position:absolute;width:480px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;border-color:orange;overflow:auto;'>
        //gridview
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have attempted your solution and am having issues I have displayed my problem as a screen capture in my question.

Comment: Move the CSS margin-top: 120px;margin-left: 60px; from the GridView rule to the scrolldiv rule in your CSS file.  As shown here: jsfiddle.net/27wYJ

Comment: Thanks for the answer marked correct worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please place grid view inside DIV tag and apply style height,width and overflow to DIV.

```
<div style="height: 100px;overflow:auto">

<asp:gridview id="grid" >

</<asp:gridview>

</div>
```

Hope this helps